# How do I run a python interpreter in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, interpreter

I just downloaded GNU emacs23.4, and I already have python3.2 installed in Windows7.

I have been using Python IDLE to edit python files.

The problem is that I can edit python files with Emacs but I do not know how to run python interpreter in Emacs. When i click on "switch to interpreter", then it says "Searching for program: no such file or directory, python"

Someone says i need to make some change on .emacs file, but i do not know where to look for.

And I am very unexperienced and just started to learn programming. I am not familiar with commonly used terminologies. I have been searching for solutions but most of the articles i find on the Internet only confuse me.

so the questions are:

1. how do i run python interpreter in Emacs?
2. are there different kind of python interpreter? if so, why do they have different interpreters for one language?

Answer (score 23):

Place this in your `.emacs` file to set the location of your python interpreter:

```
 (setq python-shell-interpreter "path\to\your\python3.2")
```

Emacs comes with good manuals and an info mode to help read them. To learn more about `.emacs` you can use:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> (info "(Emacs)Init file") <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Answer (score 16):

In emacs 25.3.1 I use this to open up a python shell:

```
M-x run-python
```

After first adding this to my .emacs file:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/usr/local/bin/python3")
```

Comment: After running `run-python` and closing it, on the second time it does not open @user8128167

Comment: or `C-c C-p` for a quicker way to run `M-x run-python`

Answer (score 14):

`C-c C-z` can do this. It is the key-binding for the command `python-switch-to-python`

Comment: python-switch-to-python will try to start a python interpreter in an Emacs buffer called '\*Python\*', if one is not already running.

Comment: This is a pretty old post, but how do you make the command point to Python 3 rather than the default Python 2.7?

Comment: @2016rshah as in other answers, one way is via `(setq python-shell-interpreter "/usr/local/bin/python3")` as needed

Answer (score 8):

IF you have python installed, try `M-x python-shell`
(press and hold ALT while pressing x, then type `python-shell`, then press enter)

There are different language implementations if that is what you are asking (see a list of them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Python_implementations)).

Comment: where do i type M, x+alt, python-shell?

Comment: the "M" stands for ALT in emacs. Just open up emacs, press and hold ALT while pressing x, and then type in python-shell

Comment: it calls(?) a black page(or buffer). i don't see the ">>>" that i can enter python commands.

Comment: In that case, refer to the answer below as you are probably missing python in your PATH variable. As a sidenote and this is my subjective opinion so take it as such : 
use cygwin (or even better some kind of linux distro) for programming purposes. You can even use a Virtual Machine to run linux inside windows for these kinds of things :)

Comment: Thank you now i finally run python interpreter in emacs. I happened to have cygwin in my PC but what is it for though?

Comment: cygwin provides you with a number of unix-like features from the commandline (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin#Features )

Comment: There is no function `python-shell` in `emacs 25.2.1`, though there are many that start with `python-shel-`. `run-python` creates a buffer `*Python*` in `inferior-python-mode`

Answer (score 4):

In emacs 24.5.1 with [spacemacs 105 (develop branch)](http://spacemacs.org/) and the Python layer enabled ("layer" is a spacemacs concept; see their documentation), I find `python-shell-switch-to-shell` opens an IPython buffer. I tested [macropy.console](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy) in such a buffer and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to have Python in your windows PATH environment variable. Can you start the interpreter just by typing `python` in the command window?

I don't have anything special in my `emacs.el`, but the start interpreter command works just fine.

Also, I recommend reading [this blog post](http://pedrokroger.com/2010/07/configuring-emacs-as-a-python-ide-2/), as it contains many useful tips and packages worth installing if using Emacs as a Python IDE.

Comment: i cannot start the interpreter just by typing python. how do i make it work that way?

Comment: Go to Control Panel's system panel (Shortcut: Windows key+Pause), click on "Advanced system settings", then the "Environment variables" button. Edit the Path environment variable in the system variables and add the path to python.exe to the current string, separated with a semicolon.

Comment: Thank you. i can start python interpreter in the command window and it works in the emacs. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

To simply open an interpreter, you can also use `M-x python`. If that does not work, try `M-x python` and hit TAB, which will list more options via auto-completion. One of them should work k if you have python installed.

If you are inclined, it may be worthwhile to check out the Emacs python modes as well - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?action=browse;oldid=PythonMode;id=PythonProgrammingInEmacs

Answer (score 0):

In emacs 24.2 there is python-switch-to-python