# Emacs shell not start python interpreter

Tags: python, shell, emacs

Windows 7, Emacs 25.1, Python 2.7

1. Start Windows prompt
2. input "python"
3. success enter to python
   [image]
4. Emacs
5. Start shell
6. input "python"

Not start python
[image]

Why?

Comment: Emacs is text-editor, why should it run python IDLE?

Comment: I think Emacs is much more than text-editor :-)

Comment: it is, but you have to configure this additional functionallity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241279/how-do-i-run-a-python-interpreter-in-emacs

Comment: but running python from cmd, will give you the python shell (IDLE). You seemed to wanting to do the same thing in Emacs? You can run python scripts in emacs using: python scriptname.py, but for using the IDLE, you will need to do some tweaking. What is you want to achieve?

Comment: explicit-shell-file-name = none. In emacs shell I start python scripts by: python my_script.py. OK. When I need to enter in python IDLE I use  windows prompt. But I want to do ALL THINGS in Emacs.

Comment: My shell-file-name=C:/Program Files/emacs/libexec/emacs/25.1/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe

Comment: @stetim94 """ Emacs is text-editor, why should it run python IDLE? """ you're funny. Emacs is a bit more, just a tiny bit.

Comment: @Alexei did you figure out how to set it up?

Comment: @A_P No, I'm not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> To start python from emacs you can start a new instance of a python
>   interpreter with the command `M-x run-python`. In my experience the
>   shell implementations in emacs is somewhat limited in functionality.
>   You can also run python from within emacs own shell implementation
>   `eshell`.

It's works. It starts a python interpreter but also it shows me a warning:
[image]